# Subgroup of a finite abelian group is isomorphic to a quotient

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, characters

The question related to title has been appeared on mathstack, and different answers are also given.

What I want to consider here is the following.

> **Fact**: A finite abelian group $G$ is isomorphic to the group $\hat{G}$ of its complex characters.

**Q.** Using the above fact, can we show easily that if $H\leq G$, $G$ finite abelian, then  there exists a subgroup $K$ of $G$ with $G/K\cong H$?

- In similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64982/is-every-quotient-of-a-finite-abelian-group-g-isomorphic-to-some-subgroup-of), the answers are using either basic structure theorem of abelian group, or other answer is avoiding characters, mentioned in note. I want to deduce from characters, but was not able to do it. Any hint could be sufficient.
- In link [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956938/subgroup-of-an-abelian-group-isomorphic-to-a-given-quotient-group?rq=1), consider exact sequence $1\rightarrow H\rightarrow G \rightarrow G/H\rightarrow 1$. Apply ${\rm Hom}(-, C^*)$, 
  $$1\rightarrow {\rm Hom}(G/H,C^*)\rightarrow {\rm Hom}(G,C^*)\rightarrow {\rm Hom}(H,C^*).$$
  Using **Fact** one can see that we have sequence $1\rightarrow \widehat{(G/H)}\rightarrow \widehat{G}\rightarrow \widehat{H}$ but the last map was not stated to be surjective; I couldn't deduce here that $\widehat{H}\cong H$ is quotient of $\widehat{G}\cong G$.

Comment: For a proof using basic structure theorems of abelian groups see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4842128/269050.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map is actually surjective, as can be seen for instance considering cardinality.